# Error "Object was open" when trying to edit records in form bound to ADO recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access, ado

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel as Integer)
Dim rsnb As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsnb = New ADODB.Recordset
rsnb.Open "SELECT * FROM QmessagesNoBill WHERE messageID='" & Me.OpenArgs & "'", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
Set Me.Recordset = rsnb 'set the forms recordset (me!) as the ADO recordset noted in SQL query above, see kb281998
rsnb.Close: Set rsnb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hitting debug on the error it highlights the first line of text in a button event:

```
Private Sub btnapprove_Click()
Me.Recordset!reviewed = 1 'mark that its been reviewed
Me.Recordset.Update
End Sub
```

Please note:

- This code works if I put the Dim statement outside of a event procedure

  - I only wanted to put it inside of the forms open event as it makes code look cleaner & I can put close statement there instead of in the forms close event
- I am new to programming & am not familiar with DAO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're supposed to close the recordset right after binding it to your form.

Try removing `rsnb.Close` from your code and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. However where do I put close connection then? I tried putting in form_close event, but it says rsnb not defined, which is correct since it exists only in private open event. Do I even have to close it or does form do that automatically for bound recordsets? If it helps this recordset is a linked SQL Server table

Comment: From my reading of kb281998 that you reference in your question, you only need to close the recordset on form onload if you're using your own data connection. Since you're using CurrentProject.Connection, it's not necessary to close the recordset on form unload.